# Angular FormData cannot append my data like in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, multipartform-data

I'm recording an audio file and sending it to a server using `multipart/formdata`. In React, my `FormData` is good, but not in Angular.

My React version works great, here it is :

```
let data = new FormData();             
data.append("file", {
uri: uri,
name: "file.m4a",
type: "audio/m4a",
});
```

If I console.log this data, I get for example :

```
{"_parts":[["file",{"uri":"file:///data/user/0/com.app/cache/Audio/recording.m4a","name":"file.m4a","type":"audio/m4a"}]]}
```

Now, I need this for Angular version, but `FormData` are not defined the same, and I don't know how to correct this.

If I do the same for Angular, I have an error :

> Argument of type '{ uri: string; name: string; type: string; }' is not
> assignable to parameter of type 'string | Blob'.

And if I `console.log` the data, I get nothing.

What is the correct version for appending my data for Angular, with these parameters ?

In Angular, the definition of FormData is :

```
declare var FormData: {
    prototype: FormData;
    new(form?: HTMLFormElement): FormData;
};
```

Comment: Check if you are importing `FormData` using a `import` statement. If your are, don't import it and it will start working the same way

Comment: I'm not, there are no imports for FormData, I added the definition on post